# Pandas Boxplots by Site Name for Months of Year

Tags: python, pandas, loops, multiple-columns, boxplot

I am trying to plot 8 different boxplots by the number of sites i have in the list "sitenames" showing the data from df3 in column "Var" for months Jan - Dec on th x axis in the list of 'months'.

```
sitenames
Out[100]: 
['BII NEE STIPA',
 'DOS ARBOLITOS',
 'PIER B',
 'PIER II',
 'PIER IV',
 'SANTIAGO',
 'VENTA III',
 'VENTOSA']
```

months = ['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER']

My code looks like this:

```
#plot by plant_name not by months
for i, plant_name in enumerate(sitenames,1):
   plt.figure()
   #df3[df3['month']==i].boxplot(by='plant_name',column='Var')
   df3[df3['plant_name']==i].boxplot(by='month',column='Var')
   plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='right')
   plt.suptitle('1991-2020 ERA5 WIND PRODUCTION',y=1)
   plt.title(months[i-1])
   plt.xlabel('SITE')
   plt.ylabel('VARIABILITY')
```

however, i get this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-101-6f80bffbda0b>", line 4, in <module>
df3[df3['plant_name']==i].boxplot(by='month',column='Var')
```

Comment: I think your condition should be `df3[df3['plant_name']==plant_name]` and not `df3[df3['plant_name']==i]`

Comment: perfect, thank you!